# Get information about function caller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have defined a custom `UIView` that contains a `UISlider`, some labels and display logic.
I put several of these custom views in the main `Viewcontroller` and have defined delegates to handle updates to the slider in the `MainController`:

CustomView.swift

```
protocol CustomDelegate {
    func sliderUpdatedWithValue(value:Float)
}

@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

var delegate:CustomDelegate? = nil

@IBAction func updateCustomSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    delegate?.sliderUpdatedWithValue(CustomSlider.value)
}
}
```

MainViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var cutomView1: CustomView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customView2: CustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cutomView1.delegate = self
        cutomView2.delegate = self
    }

    //MARK: - Delegate methods
    func sliderUpdatedWithValue(value:Float) {
        NSLog("Slider Value updated: %f", value)
    }
}
```

This works almost as intended, the only problem is that `sliderUpdatedWithValue()` gets called whenever the slider in any of the custom Views is changed and I have no way of telling which slider is sending the value.

Of course it would be trivial to add another parameter to the `sliderUpdatedWithValue()` function to include info about the containing view but I was wondering if there's a built in way to find out who called the function defined in a protocol/delegate

Comment: I would recommend including the containing view to the delegate method - this is the same pattern used in several protocols, e.g. - UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDatasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course it would be trivial to add another parameter to the `sliderUpdatedWithValue()`

This is the correct course of action. If a method needs some information that could be passed to it in a parameter, add another parameter (or modify an existing parameter to include more information, depending on your design).

Methods are one-way street, in the sense that the callee knows only what the caller wishes to disclose to it. This is true in most languages that have functions or method calls, and it is entirely by design.

Even in situations where you can get some information about the caller, for example, by analyzing the data structure which keeps track of the call stack, it is not a good idea to rely upon this structure in deciding the logic of your function.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the Info. Now that I'm sure I'm not missing something I implemented this by inititializing each CustomView with an Enum value and passing this back when calling the Delegate function. Thanks for your reply!